# Flutter filter or sort list by 2 dates

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list which I am fetching from store look like this

```
I/flutter (10562): [{lastupdate: Timestamp(seconds=1622228400, nanoseconds=0), customerName: Abc}, {lastupdate: Timestamp(seconds=1622228400, nanoseconds=0), customerName: Xyz}]
```

I want to sort this like I have 2 dates. And only those data will show which match or between these dates.

I am using datepicker for this like

```
DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();

Future<void> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
  final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: selectedDate,
      firstDate: DateTime(2021, 5),
      lastDate: DateTime(2101));
  if (picked != null && picked != selectedDate)
    setState(() {
      selectedDate = picked;
      print(restore.sort((a,b) {
        var adate = selectedDate; 
        var bdate = DateTime.now();
        return -adate.compareTo(bdate);
      }));
    });
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if you want to sort or to filter your results? Or both? And if you want to sort it, what should it sort after?

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in an earlier, now-deleted version of your question, your callback to `.sort` makes no sense.  The purpose of the `.sort` callback is to indicate the relative ordering of `a` and `b`, but your callback ignores `a` and `b` entirely and instead compares the selected date and `DateTime.now()`.

You don't say what `restore` is, and I don't know what `Timestamp` class you're using, but you should be able to do something like:

```dart
import 'dart:math';

// ...

var selectedSeconds = selectedDate.millisecondsSinceEpoch ~/ 1000;
var nowSeconds = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch ~/ 1000;

// You can avoid this if `selectedDate` is already guaranteed to be in the past 
// (or guaranteed to be in the future).
var lowerBoundSeconds = min(selectedSeconds, nowSeconds);
var upperBoundSeconds = max(selectedSeconds, nowSeconds);

var filteredList = restore.where((element) {
  var timestamp = element['lastupdate'];
  return timestamp != null &&
      timestamp.seconds >= lowerBoundSeconds &&
      timestamp.seconds <= upperBoundSeconds;
}).toList();

filteredList.sort(
    (a, b) => a['lastupdate']!.seconds.compareTo(b['lastupdate']!.seconds));
```

Note that for simplicity, the above code ignores the `nanoseconds` field.  You will need to make adjustments if you require that degree of precision.